# Using react-router in server-side rendering for multiple base path

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, react-router

I’m trying to configure my router and routes to match these two cases, depending on the environment:

1. Dev - pages will be served from 'localhost:3000/'
2. Production - served from 'www.mydomain.com/my-app/'

This is how my router looks like:

```
export default(
    <Router>
        <Route path="render" component={Render}/>
        <Route path="manage" component={Manage}/>
    </Router>
)
```

And this is how my server looks like. I’m trying to use basename to handle the scenario.

```
app.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
    let basename = '';
    if(production){
        basename = '/my-app'
    }
    match({routes: routes, location: req.url, basename: basename}, (err, redirect, props) => {
    …
});
```

I'm simulating production locally by changing the route to:

```
app.get('/my-app/*', (req, res, next) => {...})
```

I'm calling the `/render` route.

the dev environment works as expected.
the production environment doesn’t work… The matcher is trying to match the url `/my-app/render` against the routes but doesn’t find anything.

Maybe basename is not the correct solution? Or maybe I'm using it wrong?

Comment: Can you not do something like `app.get(production ? '/my-app/*' : '*', (req, res, next) => {...})`?

Comment: In production, `*` works, I have some sort of proxy behind the scenes that mapps the call to `my-app/render` to just `render`. So this path doesn't need change